# How can I upload a symfony project to gitlab?

Tags: git, symfony, gitlab

I am trying to upload a whole symfony project to gitlab. However I cannot do it from the website, because it only allows me to upload files one by one.

I was told by others to use stuff like "git add -A, git commit -m and git push origin symfony" in the command prompt, but it does not seem to be working.. I use windows 7

Comment: Yo dawg, you should try a Git tutorial. Lots of fine ones out there, e.g. https://try.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Windows, and Windows does not have  native support for GIT, you could use some GIU app. Quick Google search pointed me to GitKraken, which is free and works with GitLab, according to their website. I have not tried it myself, though.

Comment: I'd advice to learn the Git commands anyway, and not relying on a GUI. You'll better understand the concepts.

Comment: Totally agree with @Midgard. I would advice to use Linux, as well :).

Answer (score 0):

Install and open GitBash Then go to the project directory

```
cd c:\..\your_project\  
git init                      
git remote add origin 
git push -u origin master`
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows does not offer native support for git, it is advised to use a decent operating system such as Linux or Mac OSX for this. If you really need to use Windows, you can use a Git client such as [Github desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway